# Toggle div programmatically using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that when its clicked it shows a window with some information, as follows

```js
$(function() {
  $("#basicModal").collapse('toggle');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">Click to open Modal</a>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="row">
            <img src="css/cabin.jpg" class="img-responsive col-md-6" alt="conductor">
            <div class="row">
              <label>Name: </label>
              <label id="basicModal-placeName">placeName</label>
              <br>
              <label>Address: </label>
              <label id="basicModal-placeAddress">#asf-2431</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to do the same thing the first "a" tag does but programmatically and erase the that container, leaving just the code starting at the div with class modal. I have tried the following:

```
$("#basicModal").collapse('toggle');
```

But this just shows the windows and blocks the content that is inside it that is supposed to be interactive to the user. How can I achieve this?

Comment: 7 level nested `div`, somethings wrong, for sure..

Comment: @Mr.Alien Actually depressingly standard for bootstrap modals...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Hence, I like to stick with non-framework codes :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by using $('#basicModal').modal('show');